# How can I change the row height in my RecyclerView after Picasso image load?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, picasso

I currently have a RecyclerView containing posts (similar to facebook posts or tweets etc), with optional images. In the `onBindViewHolder` method of my adapter, I'm loading the image using Picasso but I won't know the size of the image until it has loaded. I want the post to appear normal (without an image) until the image has loaded, then the image should appear and the row height should increase to fit the new image with it's original aspect ratio.

At the moment when the image is loading, it's remaining attached to the bottom of the row while covering the top half of the row, even though there's a constraint from the top of the ImageView to the bottom of the main body TextView.

My item is using a ConstraintLayout as the root, the ImageView is defined as:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewMain"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textViewBody"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textViewBody"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewBody" />
```

My `onBindViewHolder` method is similar to this (I'm using Kotlin):

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HomeAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = items[position]

    val mainImage = item.imageUrl
    if (!mainImage.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        Picasso.get().load(mainImage).into(holder.imageViewMain, object: Callback{
            override fun onSuccess() {
                // Could I do something here?
            }

            override fun onError(e: Exception?) { }
        })
    }        
}
```

Has anyone got any tips on how to increase my row height when the image loads, rather than letting the image cover up the rest of the row?

Comment: Instead of using into(imageview, Callback), you can use into(Target) as per https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/Target.html

It will give you the Bitmap directly on success, from where you can 1.Get its dimensions 2. Expand your layout accordingly 3. Load the bitmap inside the ImageView

Comment: I think that you need better control of the parent dimension, specifically `height`. You didn't pass on `ConstrainLayout`, but I'm guessing that you just need to add `wrap_content` for `height`, and maybe notify `RecyclerView` when Image is loaded.

Comment: My parent `ConstraintLayout` already has `wrap_content` height. How would I notify the `RecyclerView` when the image is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//set visibility gone
//set height 250dp
// set scale_type = fitXY
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewMain"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:visibility="Gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textViewBody"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textViewBody"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewBody" />
```

In your function

```
// set visibility Visible in onSuccess callback.
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HomeAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
val item = items[position]

val mainImage = item.imageUrl
if (!mainImage.isNullOrEmpty()) {
    Picasso.get().load(mainImage).into(holder.imageViewMain, object: Callback{
        override fun onSuccess() {
            // Could I do something here?
            holder.imageViewMain.setVisibility(View.Visible)
        }

        override fun onError(e: Exception?) { }
    })
}        
}
```

Comment: The issue is that I don't know the size/shape of the image in advance, I want the row height to change so that the image remains full width and the height changes. Won't this method just let me have no image or a 250dp tall image?

Comment: Fix the height of your imageview and by using property scaletype=fitXY it will give you the view with full width and fixed height

Comment: and make imageview width match_parent

Comment: I should have specified, I need to keep the original aspect ratio of the image

Comment: k, so make it wrap content and scaletype=fitCenter

Comment: now you only have to visible the imageview in onSuccess callback

Comment: That's why i'm saying fixed the height, because when image load its takes the original height like 800px or may be 1500px, when you get this type of height you cannot control the view.

Comment: And is this a List? were you loading imageview

Comment: It's a RecyclerView, the ImageView is being loaded in the `onCreateViewHolder` method of my adapter

Comment: k, If you want the image to be fit screen then you have take the height of the device dynamically and set to imageview.

Comment: I don't want the image to fit the screen, I want the RecyclerView row to fit the image while maintaining the aspect ratio and fixed width

Comment: can you upload your output